# What does "Out of memory on a ...-byte allocation" mean? (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

What does these numbers mean below? (caught with LogCat debugger)

```
08-03 14:29:11.538: I/dalvikvm-heap(6514): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 14337016-byte allocation
08-03 14:29:11.568: D/dalvikvm(6514): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 6% free 115756K/121948K, paused   29ms, total 30ms
08-03 14:29:11.568: E/dalvikvm-heap(6514): Out of memory on a 14337016-byte allocation.
```

- What does 121948K and 115756K mean?
- Why 14337016 byte? It is ~14MB. It's impossible! I tried to load a bitmap with 14kB size.

Comment: ur application is trying to request more memory to OS.and OS refuse to allocate..so this exception raised..!!

Comment: Are you sure the image is 14KB? Also, you should realize that Android won't usually pick the best format for your image. I might be mistaken, but it will usually pick a 32bpp format. Also, if you're using a color pallette in the native image (for example .bmp or .gif) I believe Android will toss that and convert to ARGB or RGB pixels.

Answer (score 2):

system is trying to free unused memory in order to be able to find some more resources for your application

`GC_BEFORE_OOM` happens your app's running out of its heap space

more about `GC_BEFORE_OOM` can be found [here](http://git.omapzoom.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob;f=vm/alloc/Heap.cpp;h=9eee817e5e5cc1115041c5548214292a7f6e1090;hb=HEAD)

Numbers:
gc freed 10K, 6% is free, which is too little, so it continues deallocation further until gc reaches oom. 115756K/121948K is statistics of the heap of your application

[image]

more information about the memory can be found by watching this [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=relmfu)

Comment: It's not necessarily a memory leak, he's just trying to allocate more memory than his app is allowed

Comment: @Samuel you are right, deleting `memory leak` words from my answer

Comment: @Samuel but it is on the edge of leaking the memory, because gc does not make your application immune to memory leaks and since `GC_BEFORE_OOM` is taking over gc, then it means that something fishy is happening there with memory allocation

Comment: That happens because he's trying to allocate a big chunk of memory. GC is triggered to try to deallocate enough memory for the allocation to be successful. That's the BEFORE_OOM part. If there were a lot of unused objects that hadn't been GC'd, the `GC_BEFORE_OOM` could help save the app and prevent an out of memory exception. I do agree that there might be a memory leak somewhere that is causing his memory to run out, but it's impossible to say.

Comment: What does "Out of memory on a 14337016-byte allocation" mean? 
Does it mean, that the VM would like to allocate ~14 MegaByte memory???
All of my Bitmaps are 2,5MB altogether.

Comment: @Marton_hun No, it means that you heap (which is assigned to you application) reached its maximum allocation limit. So it means that ~14Mb memory is already allocated

Comment: @Marton_hun it is not just your Bitmaps that are being allocated in memory (though they take lots of space), but it is everything that is instantiated using `new ..` keyword

Comment: I took references to 10 inflated (full screen)layouts and I keep them (I don't null these references). Could it cause the memory problems?

Comment: @Marton_hun man, i cannot tell, I don't know what you are doing or why you are doing this, you haven't shown any code of yours, so I can only tell you what those lines from yout logcat mean, I cannot just imagine your code